# WordPress updates on admin panel vs c-panel

Tags: wordpress

Have a client with a WestHost hosting account and a WordPress site.  Updating of the WordPress version and plugin versions is available both from the hosting provided C-Panel and from the WordPress admin dashboard.  Is there any difference between these two methods - is one better than the other?

Answer (score 0):

Both methods should preform the same task in the end. Because you have access to the cPanel, the added benefit is that you can download a backup incase things break once you update the versions.